# Stream a command's response up to node

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm trying to make a node package which executes a permanent script that keeps printing data and passes it to a package caller.

I use the exec object, in order to call this command:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// ...

exec("script always", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
        throw error;
    }
    // here's where everything gets messy
    if(callback)
        callback(stream)
});
```

This command keeps printing data until I stop it. Now, how could I stream this console output to a node event another wants to implement? I've been reading about the [Readable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), but I don't know how to tie it all together (actually, heh, they have the function `getReadableStreamSomehow()` for the sake of the examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `spawn`, not `exec`, as described [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html). This will return an object where you have direct access to the program's streams, so you can easily `pipe` them, e.g., or subscribe to their `data` events.

See [this example](http://www.hacksparrow.com/using-node-js-to-download-files.html#nodejs-curl) for a sample on how to capture output of the `curl` command.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Aha! Yeah, that solved the issue. As a sidenote, spawn seems to only accept the full command in the `'command', ['arg1', 'arg2']` mode, otherwise it just doesn't work at all.